# Bind WPF user control property inside code

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a `MainWindow.xaml` that has a user control and a `ToggleButton`:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="toggle" Content="Wait" />
```

This button sets `BusyDecorator` User control property called `IsBusyIndicatorShowing`, it works as expected, whenever user clicks on toggLe button it sets user control property:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"  
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ctrls="clr-namespace:Controls"
    Title="Busy" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="322*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="53*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ToggleButton x:Name="toggle" Content="Show" Margin="228,12,255,397" />
        <ctrls:BusyDecorator  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsBusyIndicatorShowing="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=toggle}">
            <Image  Name="canvas" Stretch="Fill"  Margin="5" />
         </ctrls:BusyDecorator>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I want to bind BusyDecorator’s `IsBusyIndicatorShowing` property in code.
To do so I added  `IsBusyIndicatorShowing="{Binding IsBusyIndicatorShowing}"` inside user control in xaml like

```
<ctrls:BusyDecorator   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="Actions" IsBusyIndicatorShowing="{Binding IsBusyIndicatorShowing}">
  ...
```

But I do not know hot to define and set property inside code like

```
public bool doSomething()
    {
       //init
       //toggle user control
       BusyDecorator.IsBusyIndicatorShowing = true;
       //do stuff
       //toggle user control
       BusyDecorator.IsBusyIndicatorShowing = false;
       return true;
    }
```

It does not work because it says

```
Error   2   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Controls.BusyDecorator.IsBusyIndicatorShowing.get'
```

Comment: Could you give a further explanation what do yo want to do? Because I do not understand your question.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do inside the method doSomething? And in which context is it executed?

Comment: `Datacontext = this;` I want to emulate the toggleButton Programatically, I mean, To delete it from xaml and emulate the action programatically to activate user control

Comment: `Datacontext = this;` is a huge code smell.  Don't do that.  Also, it wouldn't work anyhow, as your work is being done in the UI thread and so the UI wouldn't be updated until you are done.  That's a common error.

Comment: So How do I define user control  `IsBusyIndicatorShowing` property, and how to toggle it inside code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is the key to your problem, assuming I understand your question correctly. When you say `"BusyDecorator.IsBusyIndicatorShowing = true"` you are using the BusyDecorator class definition (as though it is static), not the instance you have defined in your XAML.

You should be able to name your XAML instance (note the x:Name):

```
<ctrls:BusyDecorator x:Name="myBusyDecorator" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsBusyIndicatorShowing="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=toggle}">
            <Image  Name="canvas" Stretch="Fill"  Margin="5" />
         </ctrls:BusyDecorator>
```

Then you should be able to refer to that instance in code and access the property in whatever event you desire as such:

```
myBusyDecorator.IsBusyIndicatorShowing = true;
```

Comment: Damn it was that easy, Thank you so much Bobby.